# Strange coordinate system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, latitude-longitude

Here's an extract of a feature from the web that I converted to geojson using qgis. However, the coordinates are not standard are at all and when trying to actually preview it on the web it fails, however, qgis has no problem reading it. My question is how do I transform this set of coordinates using QGis into "standard" coordinates. Data comes from here http://donnees.ville.montreal.qc.ca/dataset/affectation-du-sol/resource/c38ea3f0-fa70-48c9-9421-92113c581b69

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::900913" } },

"features": [
 { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "categorie": "rural" }, "geometry": { "type":     "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ -8232754.718677375465631, 5691987.542297831736505, 0.0 ], [ -8232826.554151621647179, 5691863.061614270322025, 0.0 ]
```

Here is the prj file

```
PROJCS["Ontario_MTM_Zone_8_east_of_75_degrees_W_NAD_83_datum",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["Geodetic_Reference_System_of_1980",6378137,298.2572221008916]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-73.5],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9999],PARAMETER["false_easting",304800],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

Comment: Do you want Geographic Lat/Lng?

Comment: well this world is completely unknown for me, something that lets say a google map could read, this http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24340/how-to-convert-coordinates-from-meters-to-decimal-degrees actually solved my problem, had to save the layer as EPGS:4326

Comment: ewwwww Ontario MTM... that's a toughie!!!

Comment: why is this question off-topic? i agree that the title is weak but the actual question is valid.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure the file in qgis "lines up" with reality (check with openlayers plugin wether it matches with bing maps)
2. Select your layer in qgis and in the "layer"-menu, go to "save as" and define wich CRS you want to convert the data to.
3. You can even define what datatype you want your data in.

Answer (score 0):

Projection file looks like EPSG 2950: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2950/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add proj4js support to your project and define the projection with the information from the [spatialreference](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/2950/) page.

I put your shape file into QGIS. Exported the lot to geoJson in the native projection (EPSG:2950).

Add the proj4s library and define the projection like so.

```
proj4.defs('EPSG:2950', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=-73.5 +k=0.9999 +x_0=304800 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs');
```

Thereafter you can read the geoJson by defining the dataProjection and featureProjection.

```
var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geoJson,{
  dataProjection: 'EPSG:2950',
  featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
});
```

I extracted a smaller feature from the geojson export and created a jsFiddle.

Have a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/goldrydigital/8nbsn2u4/).