# ArcGIS - Convert a Shapefile into JSON with coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, json

I have a shapefile and I would like to convert in ESRI Json with ArcGIS toolbox From feature to JSON.
When i convert it I visualize x and y values in meters while I want latitude and longitude information.
How can I set this option to visualize geo coordinates in json file?

Comment: So, you have a shapefile that is defined in projected coordinate system (meters as units) and when you convert it to JSON you get meters as well, but you want to have JSON coordinates defined in a geographic coordinate system (decimal degrees)?

Comment: Yes, my shapefile is defined in this way: PROJCS["WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_32N",GEOGCS["GCS_WGS_1984",DATUM["D_WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS_1984",6378137.0,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",9.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0]] I want a json file with geo coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved this proble following procedure at this link.

[How to convert coordinates from meters to decimal degrees?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24340/how-to-convert-coordinates-from-meters-to-decimal-degrees)

Comment: So you used QGis?

Comment: Yes! I've used QGIS to obtain a new shape file with coordinates in degree and then I've converted it in ArcGIS using FeatureToJSON toolbox.

Answer (score 4):

Some of the geoprocessing tools in ArcGIS respect [output coordinate system](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Output_Coordinate_System/001w00000005000000/) environment setting, but not this one.

You need to run the [Project tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Project/00170000007m000000/) beforehand creating a projected shapefile first (use the WGS 1984 GCS). This will create a new shapefile on the disk with coordinates defined in lat/long.

Comment: I' ve launched the script as indicated in [Project Tool]( http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Project/00170000007m000000/) but I receive following error Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 949, in __init__
    self._arc_object.createFromFile(item)
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Errore durante l'esecuzione della funzione.

Comment: You may need to define the proper transformation.

Comment: I' ve defined the transformation as follow:WGS 1984 UTM Zone 32N.  I've executed this script and I correctly generate a new shapefile. What is the next step to obtain the json file with coordinates?

Comment: You run the same GP tool as you did, Features to JSON. Because you have your features in geographic coordinate system, the geometry coordinates will be exported with decimal degrees.

Comment: I've used GP tool Features to JSON but the result is the same. Results are  in meters. Where's the error?

Comment: Make sure the feature class (shapefile) you got from the Project tool has geographic coordinate system. This can be tested by creating a new map document and ArcMap and adding it into the map. Check the Layers (data frame) coordinate system and report it here.