# Converting shapefile CRS from WGS to UTM in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, convert, utm

I want to calculate point distance but the result is null, and apparently it is because the point and the raster file have different CRS.
The raster is UTM, and the point is WGS84

I follow the tutorial from here [How to convert coordinates from meters to decimal degrees?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24340/how-to-convert-coordinates-from-meters-to-decimal-degrees)

However, the point file is the text file I input by myself using a decimal degree for the coordinate. I opened it as delimited text layer, it open perfectly. Then I save as the text layer into ESRI shapefile. At this point the coordinate system is in WGS 84.

Then I tried to save as the shapefile into another file with a different UTM CRS,
[image]

but this error message appear 
[image]

I think there is an option to convert manually the decimal degree coordinates in text file to UTM.Maybe using converter available on the internet. However most of the free converter I found only do it one by one, meanwhile I have around 1200 sampling points. So it will be very time-consuming.

Anybody have insight how to convert it?

Comment: can you share the file or a sample of the points?

Comment: [UTM48N](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/wgs-84-utm-zone-48n/) (like all UTM projections) is not defined above 84° north. Do some of your features exceed this limit?

Comment: ... abd the extent notes that it goes up North to 102.7 degrees. That`s wrong for sure.

Comment: Did you create this data from a text file or spreadsheet? You've got the X and Y columns mixed up. Re-import the data, and swap the coordinate columns.

Comment: Here is the data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u4mw8jy3whhc5j8/AT%20plot.csv?dl=0 I created it using spreadsheet. I already swapped the column, it still not working. Same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTM zone 48N is valid between 102°E and 108°E. You can exceed those limits a bit, but a point at 0.099°E is definitely out of the limits of the projection.

Try to clip your vector file to your study area, or continue with some other projection.

Comment: The OP swapped the data columns when he imported the data (or someone else did) or the original data is just screwed up.

Comment: I write it in the excel with first column as latitude and second column as longitude. I swapped them, but the error message still the same

Comment: In GIS world, it is longitude-latitude order in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I found what the error is. In the entry number 1071-1200 the lat-long is reversed. It all the problem with the entry, my bad.

Thank you for your helps :D