# Shapefile to KML not rendering in Google Earth

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, coordinate-system, google-earth

I have this shapefile which does not open in Google Earth when converted to kml.

GCS: WGS1984

PCS: UTM, zone 41N

I have been trying it with GCS only but it still does not work. I have been using the define projection and Feature--> project tools but it did not work either... other kml files, on my system, are working.

Can someone indicate where I'm getting it all wrong. I have seen and tried solutions given in similar questions:

[How to convert coordinates from meters to decimal degrees?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24340/how-to-convert-coordinates-from-meters-to-decimal-degrees)

but they don't help, but, rather, I lost the file and see an empty canvas. Google Earth positions it somewhere in the Arctic but the polygon etc are not visible.

The coordinate system is in meters which I normally have in decimal degrees.

Comment: When you display your shapefile in arcmap with, say, another reference layer, does it line up properly?

Comment: Yes it does. I am working on this document being used for carrying out updates. I'm not getting it but 2 of the layers have geographical and UTM projection both. This file is one of them. Rest of the shapefiles are only geographically projected, They work really fine everywhere but do not render on Google Earth.

Comment: It looks like this might be a bug, unless it is some kind of symbology or reference scale issue. What reference scale do you use? Is your layer visible in your arcmap document at that scale? Did you install the latest ServicePack for ArcGIS?

Comment: My ArcGIS is working just fine as I mentioned all my other files are working properly. I have least idea about this. Else, problems of similar nature have been occurring previously and I'd solve them easily.

Comment: Just to be clear:

The **Define Projection** geoprocessing tool does not change the data, it simply overwrites (or creates) the projection currently set to that dataset.  (In the case of a shapefile it's the .prj file.)

The **Project** geprocessing tool will create a new dataset based upon your source dataset's defined projection.

I would:

 1. Open a new mxd and add the source (unaltered) dataset.
 2. Click File -> Add Data -> Add Basemap -> Select one (e.g. Streets).

Are you in the correct location?

Comment: yup... Location is correct... I tried it with basemap as well...